# Docker stopping after first line

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jpetazzo/dind
ENV debian_frontend noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.conf
COPY wrapdocker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/wrapdocker.conf
CMD supervisord -c /etc/supervisor.conf
```

Running it gives me an `EOF`:

```
$docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM jpetazzo/dind
EOF
```

I am on *Ubuntu 14.04*:

```
$docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Any clue why is there an `EOF`?

I tried to re-copy the file in another directory, it didn't change anything. Changing `FROM jpetazzo/dind` to `FROM ubuntu` does change things.

**EDIT**: 
The logs created during the mistake:

```
/var/log/upstart$ sudo cat docker.log 

INFO[0568] POST /v1.19/build?cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior locally. Is your docker daemon logging any errors?

Comment: where could I check that ?

Comment: /var/log/upstart$ sudo cat docker.log 
INFO[0568] POST /v1.19/build?cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=

Comment: to find the docker's logs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-produce that error by using your `Dockerfile` without success:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM jpetazzo/dind
 ---> e82a08f5b4e3
Step 1 : ENV debian_frontend noninteractive
 ---> Running in bb205a0e8238
 ---> e1e5993a94b7
Removing intermediate container bb205a0e8238
Step 2 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Running in 1004dda4c147
Get:1 https://get.docker.com docker InRelease
Ign https://get.docker.com docker InRelease
Hit https://get.docker.com docker Release.gpg
Hit https://get.docker.com docker Release
...
```

Are you sure that you do not have networking issues on the host where your Docker daemon runs?

I am using the same Docker server/client version like you.