# docker daemon logs are missing

Tags: logging, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am looking for the docker-**daemon** logs, the ones that display information between the docker client and the docker daemon.

According to this answer: [Where is the Docker daemon log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log)

The log is supposed to be in `/var/log/docker.log` for boot2docker (I am running docker on windows).

However, boot2docker is deprecated and replaced by `docker-machine`.

Regardless, I do not have the directory or log file listed above. I do not even have a /var directory.

After creating one the above log file in the specified path, the daemon did not even write to the docker.log file as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `boot2docker` or `docker-machine` you first need to ssh into that VM with `docker-machine ssh <machineName>`. There you will find the `/var/log/` folder.

Comment: Thanks, you are always helpful. Another way I figured out to get in (and it is a bit easier to see) is through the oracle virtual box. Click 'Show' on the VM you wanna see, which will open up the command line terminal