# docker pull/push not working with insecure registry

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

I installed docker toolbox and I am trying to connect to my private registry.

I added the following to `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`

```
 EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox --insecure-registry http://myregistry.com:80

'
```

I am able to login to the registry successfully. But when I try to pull/push from/to the registry, I get the following error.

```
Error response from daemon: unable to ping registry endpoint
https://myregistry.com:80/v0/ v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get
https://myregistry.com:80/v2/: tls: oversized record received with
length 20527  v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get
https://myregistry.com:80/v1/_ping: tls: oversized record received
with length 20527
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the issue.

instead of

```
--insecure-registry http://myregistry.com:80
```

I did

```
--insecure-registry=myregistry.com
```

and it worked

Comment: Good feedback, more specific than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

The main way to debug, as in [issue 958](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/958#issuecomment-138623430), is to run the daemon docker in debug:

```
docker -D -d
```

In your case, the v2 registry was not able to be contacted and then attempted v1, giving the error you see.
[The **logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970134/6309) should tell you more.

Make sure you have followed [Deploying a plain HTTP registry](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/1c5f8166e4ea5e97251a9d539acbd52f40955756/docs/insecure.md#deploying-a-plain-http-registry).

Comment: Thanks @VonC. The problem is, when I login it uses "http://" and when I pull it uses "https://". I am not sure why. I don't know what am I missing.

Comment: @ShriramSharma That reminds me of https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1028#issuecomment-148958771 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17317, but you don't have nginx in your setup, do you?

Comment: No I don't have nginx

Comment: @ShriramSharma then trying a debug session might be able to tell you more with the docker logs.