# Docker service won't stay alive

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have some problem on my ubuntu 14.04.  When i do

```
$ sudo service docker start 
docker start/running, process 30447
```

And after

```
$ sudo service docker status
docker stop/waiting
```

I tried to puge/autoclean and reinstall docker-engine that always have this problem

Thank you :)

**EDIT**
My /var/log/upstart/docker.log

`time="2016-04-28T14:21:36.327412687+02:00" level=info msg="previous instance of containerd still alive (2099)"

time="2016-04-28T14:21:36.427058459+02:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"aufs\""

time="2016-04-28T14:21:36.436012041+02:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"

time="2016-04-28T14:21:36.445407999+02:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"

time="2016-04-28T14:21:36.463832409+02:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain: Iptables not found"`

Comment: Is there anything in the logs? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970134/1871033

Comment: That last error seems fairly clear.  Is `iptables` available on your system (it would be unusual for it to be missing, but it doesn't hurt to check)?  Does it work (i.e., can you create/delete iptables rules)? Are you running a stock kernel or have you built a custom kernel of some sort?

Comment: I've reinstall iptable and delete all rules [http://serverfault.com/questions/200635/linux-iptables-best-way-to-clear-all-rules-leaving-anything-open](http://serverfault.com/questions/200635/linux-iptables-best-way-to-clear-all-rules-leaving-anything-open) and that work ! \o/ ty :)