# Where is the Docker daemon log on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: logging, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's the information about the system:

```
 ~ $ /usr/bin/lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
 ~ $ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 54
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 62
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-73-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.86 GiB
Name: ncooprider-tron
ID: MXYF:MYLL:QD3U:VT7L:RIAK:DOZR:RAYR:7ZD6:7ODV:R4E3:MFEU:BQBE
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
 ~ $ uname -a
Linux ncooprider-tron 3.16.0-73-generic #95~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 08:00:04 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There's no `upstart` directory in `/var/log` and I do not have the `journalctl` command in my path. When I look at the Docker daemon process, it says it's started by init (PID 1 as parent) and has the `--raw-logs` argument.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/var/log/syslog` records docker daemon logs

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep docker`