# Converting gp2 to gp3 with running docker host on jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

So i tried to make a dummy instance for converting EBS volume from gp2 to gp3 installed docker and hosted Jenkins on it to check if it will effect or not so what i was able to find docker container and Jenkins got stopped, can any one help me on this why it stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to inspect the logs via docker of the container in question to find out why it stopped. Some good steps to follow on debugging this from another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38113168/5143829