# Docker daemon log for Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

This is similar to [Where is the Docker daemon log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log). 
But more for **Docker Desktop for Mac**.

Where can I find the daemon log for **Docker Desktop for Mac**?

Comment: do docker-machine ssh (name) and same location as linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer at:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#/checking-the-logs

In short, the logs can be found using

```
syslog -k Sender Docker
```

or using the inbuilt Mac Console.

Comment: I am not convinced those log entires include entries from docker daemon. Just tested with one container and did not see any new entries in syslog. However I can see them in `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/log/docker.log`.

Comment: Doesn't work on Catalina. "Most system logs have moved to a new logging system."

Answer (score 10):

- Docker For Mac (Beta) - `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/log/docker.log`

Comment: Is this path for the new xhyve based docker for mac beta?

Comment: tail -f  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/log/vm/docker.log

Answer (score 3):

For future travellers, it's no longer available ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/log/docker.log.

As per the new documentation, you can need to execute the following:

```
$ pred='process matches ".*(ocker|vpnkit).*"
  || (process in {"taskgated-helper", "launchservicesd", "kernel"} && eventMessage contains[c] "docker")'
$ /usr/bin/log stream --style syslog --level=debug --color=always --predicate "$pred"
```

See more here - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#check-the-logs

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, for Docker versions greater than 18.01:

`$ cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/`

Find the full list of daemon logs locations at:
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#read-the-logs

Comment: On my Macbook, with Docker Engine 19.03.02 (Docker Desktop 2.1.0.3) there are no logs at this location.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be best on modern macOS releases (High Sierra+):

`log stream --predicate 'eventMessage contains "docker"'`

Answer (score 0):

For a boot2docker based VM the path is `/var/lib/boot2docker/docker.log`.
This can be accessed with `docker-machine`

```
docker-machine ssh default sudo cat /var/lib/boot2docker/docker.log
```

For the new xhyve based Docker for Mac see [Lauri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38156270/1318694).