# ZFS storage on Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, zfs

I would like to try out ZFS on Ubuntu(16.04) docker container. Followed the following https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/zfs-driver/

```
> lsmod | grep zfs
zfs                  2813952  5
zunicode              331776  1 zfs
zcommon                57344  1 zfs
znvpair                90112  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   102400  3 zfs,zcommon,znvpair
zavl                   16384  1 zfs
```

Listing the ZFS mounts

```
>sudo zfs list
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zpool-docker          261K   976M  53.5K  /zpool-docker
zpool-docker/docker   120K   976M   120K  /var/lib/docker
```

After starting docker

```
> sudo docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: zfs
 Dirs: 0
 ...
```

Wonder why I still get **Storage Driver: aufs & Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs" in place of zfs?

Also how can I map "/zpool-docker" into the Ubuntu container image?

Comment: `aufs` is the fallback when anything fails. What does the [docker daemon log](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970134) at startup?

Comment: Can find docker daemon logs @ /var/log/upstart/docker.log. How to enable daemon logging. FYI, I start docker daemon "sudo service docker start". Not sure of I need to pass some flag for getting logs

Comment: I thought it would have been logging already... `/etc/default/docker` and `/etc/init/docker.conf` should detail the docker daemon options. You could temporarily add a `-D` for debug or `--log-level=info`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have:

- a ZFS pool (let's call it `data`)
- a ZFS dataset mounted on `/var/lib/docker` (created with a command along the line of: `zfs create -o mountpoint=/var/lib/docker data/docker`)

Then:

Stop your docker daemon (eg. `systemctl stop docker.service`)

Create a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` or amend it to contain a line with `"storage-driver"` set to `zfs`:

```
{
...
        "storage-driver": "zfs"
...
}
```

Restart your docker daemon.

`docker info` should now reveal:

```
Storage Driver: zfs
Zpool: data
Zpool Health: ONLINE
Parent Dataset: data/docker
```