# Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: docker

So I installed docker engine on RHEL 7

Now when I do a

```
service docker start
```

I get the following error:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and when I go to "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe"
I get:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─docker.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-09-08 22:15:53 EDT; 10s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 13504 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --mtu 1400 --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13504 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com docker[13504]: time="2016-09-08T22:15:53.227074798-04:00" level=fatal msg="no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service ...by systemd"
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

And

--

```
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 08 22:10:01 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com CROND[12753]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep 08 22:10:01 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Starting Session 58 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-58.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-58.scope has begun starting up.
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com polkitd[766]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12878:2674931 (system bus name :1.173 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com docker[12895]: time="2016-09-08T22:10:53.413304246-04:00" level=fatal msg="no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Sep 08 22:10:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com polkitd[766]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12878:2674931 (system bus name :1.173, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
Sep 08 22:13:36 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com polkitd[766]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:13214:2691210 (system bus name :1.174 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Sep 08 22:13:36 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com polkitd[766]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:13214:2691210 (system bus name :1.174, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com polkitd[766]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:13489:2704913 (system bus name :1.175 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com docker[13504]: time="2016-09-08T22:15:53.227074798-04:00" level=fatal msg="no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Sep 08 22:15:53 app-linux2.app-netapp.lab.com polkitd[766]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:13489:2704913 (system bus name :1.175, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
lines 3473-3523/3523 (END)
```

I tried to search solution for this 
but could not find any.

Comment: Report this to Docker (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues). Also include the commands you use to install the docker daemon.

Answer (score 3):

Check your OS logs files for warning or error messages.
Probably you have made a mistake in the config files of docker and when the service starts it gets an error.

The log's location depends on your OS. 
On Linux system logs are often in:

- `/var/log/daemon.log`
- `/var/log/docker`
- `/var/log/messages`
- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`

Some useful linux console commands to inspect docker logs:

- `sudo systemctl status docker.service`
- `sudo journalctl -fu docker.service`
- `cat /var/log/daemon.log | grep docker`
- `cat /var/log/messages | grep docker`

If you are using Windows this article might be [helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/troubleshooting#finding-logs)
Here are more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log)

Answer (score 2):

What version of Docker do you use? If you are not locked to the elder one, consider use of the most recent version (currently it's `1.12`). Here's my startup options (Debian 8, `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --dns=10.240.116.7 --dns 8.8.8.8  --bip=172.17.42.1/24
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also try to start Docker in debug mode (`-D`) without `systemd`, just like if it was a common program. This will help to find out why daemon doesn't start.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the `Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` problem, for me this worked:

- create `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker/`
- put this in it:

  `{`
    `"exec-root": "/path/to/docker/run",`
   `"storage-driver": "overlay",`
    `"graph": "/path/to/docker/lib"`
  `}`
- then try: `docker daemon`
- reboot
- `docker run hello-world` should succeed now

Answer (score 2):

Just Remove Docker Lib and restart it again with:

```
sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/docker
```

then

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: This deletes all the docker information. I wouldn't recommend this as a first step.

Comment: sorry but you have not any chance on this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I came across same issue in my Linux VM(virtual machine).
System details : ubuntu 18.04
I had to just delete my `daemon.json` and then do a `service docker start` this worked for me.

**Note**: I had put insecure registry in my daemon.json file and i didn't want that as well hence i deleted it. I don't know it's usage though.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for docker service failing to run. One of them that I encountered is using single quotes instead of double quotes for the key value pairs in the json file.

**It fails**

```
sudo cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json << '_EOF'
{
    'registry-mirrors': ['https://docker.io'] 
}
_EOF
```

**It works!**

```
sudo cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json << '_EOF'
{
    "registry-mirrors": ["https://docker.io"] 
}
_EOF
```

For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355655/1691723)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after changing the docker config file:

> /etc/docker/daemon.json

and I found the json I typed was in wrong format, after correcting it, the problem was solved.