# What causes Gitlab's CI pipeline to return "Job Failed (system failure): aborted: terminated"

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

A couple times now, in different projects, seemingly at totally unrelated places in the CI process, part-way through a pipeline job/build, it will just fail, printing at the end of the log:

"ERROR: Job Failed (system failure): aborted: terminated"

I can't find any reference to what causes this outcome.  Any ideas why it would be happening intermittently, or how to narrow down the cause?

Comment: Which runner are you using ?

Comment: Umm... docker?  Is that specific enough? :)

Comment: yes thanks :) This could be a failure coming from outside the container, do you have access to the server logs ? Or the docker logs (see here for a way to get them : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970134/2335212 )