# I can't deploy a Docker Swarm service using ubuntu based image

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm a newbie in Docker/Docker Swarm and I want to create a custom mosquitto service on Swarm. I created a custom mosquitto image 
`lcsf/mosquitto3` from ubuntu:latest, then I added some tools (ping, ipconfig). I can run a single container with `docker run` and `/bin/bash`, but I can't create a Swarm service with that image. The service isn't created successfully. There are some outputs below.

Dockerfile:

`FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y mosquitto mosquitto-clients
EXPOSE 80 443 1883 8083 8883`

Docker service create output:

`overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks
1/1: preparing [========>            ]
verify: Detected task failure`

This output is shown in a loop, then I stop it using ctrl+c, the service is created, but doesn't run, with 0/1 replicas.

Docker service ps mqtt (my custom name) output, there are 3 nodes.

`ID                  NAME                IMAGE                    NODE

DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR               PORTS
llqr0gysz4bj        mqtt.1              lcsf/mosquitto3:latest   Docker02            Ready               Ready 2 seconds ago
kcwfqovyn2mp         \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 2 seconds ago
ruisy599nbt4         \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 7 seconds ago
xg1lib5x8vt9         \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest   Docker02            Shutdown            Complete 13 seconds ago
fgm9wu25t0lj         \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 18 seconds ago`

That's it, I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance and I'm sorry 'bout my English and Stack Overflow skills.

UPDATE #1

Output from `journalctl -f -n10` command after tying to create the service:

`Sep 25 09:01:03 Docker01 dockerd[1230]: time="2017-09-25T09:01:03.692391553-04:00" level=info msg="Node join event for Docker02-a9b6d39043d3/192.168.222.51"
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 systemd-udevd[31966]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth8e5ebcb: No such file or directory
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 systemd-udevd[31967]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethaf2978b: No such file or directory
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered blocking state
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered disabled state
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: device vethaf2978b entered promiscuous mode
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethaf2978b: link is not ready
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: eth0: renamed from veth8e5ebcb
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethaf2978b: link becomes ready
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered blocking state
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered forwarding state
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered disabled state
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: veth8e5ebcb: renamed from eth0
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered disabled state
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: device vethaf2978b left promiscuous mode
Sep 25 09:01:15 Docker01 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaf2978b) entered disabled state
Sep 25 09:01:33 Docker01 dockerd[1230]: time="2017-09-25T09:01:33.693508463-04:00" level=info msg="Node join event for Docker03-f71a448c54c7/192.168.222.52"
Sep 25 09:01:46 Docker01 dockerd[1230]: time="2017-09-25T09:01:46.541311475-04:00" level=info msg="Node join event for Docker02-a9b6d39043d3/192.168.222.51"
Sep 25 09:01:57 Docker01 dockerd[1230]: sync duration of 3.001217113s, expected less than 1s
Sep 25 09:02:03 Docker01 dockerd[1230]: time="2017-09-25T09:02:03.694876667-04:00" level=info msg="Node join event for Docker03-f71a448c54c7/192.168.222.52"
Sep 25 09:02:33 Docker01 dockerd[1230]: time="2017-09-25T09:02:33.695993259-04:00" level=info msg="Node join event for Docker03-f71a448c54c7/192.168.222.52"`

UPDATE #2

This is the output from `docker service ps --no-trunc mqtt` command

`ID                          NAME                IMAGE                                                                                            NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                     ERROR               PORTS
bour693j8jbbrt799fz0nkpwr   mqtt.1              lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker03            Ready               Ready 4 seconds ago
wro6254cs94gkijs8s4v9cvim    \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 4 seconds ago
7vgx2mehaxki2p680fesn5jww    \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 10 seconds ago
52hv6da6mj72s64po3hze4ham    \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 15 seconds ago
e3s383vtg0idw8ryxwh2y3gmu    \_ mqtt.1          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker03            Shutdown            Complete 21 seconds ago
90i30f3riwka8xs187xi7uxt2   mqtt.2              lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker02            Ready               Ready less than a second ago
p2lzd04tinjdjkwkr26umlh9a    \_ mqtt.2          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker02            Shutdown            Complete less than a second ago
q8awoj8uu7gad6hvonhl4t9f1    \_ mqtt.2          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker02            Shutdown            Complete 6 seconds ago
1fuqt0et7vw1vntd8p62jiiut    \_ mqtt.2          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker02            Shutdown            Complete 11 seconds ago
k3vlusok792zw0v3yddxqlmg3    \_ mqtt.2          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker02            Shutdown            Complete 17 seconds ago
i4tywshqv4pxsyz5tz0z0evkz   mqtt.3              lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker01            Ready               Ready less than a second ago
44ee4iqqpkeome4lokx9ykmbo    \_ mqtt.3          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker01            Shutdown            Complete less than a second ago
kdx273e9fkpqkafztif1dz35q    \_ mqtt.3          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker01            Shutdown            Complete 6 seconds ago
l2oewfnwbkia94r6rifbcfi4h    \_ mqtt.3          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker01            Shutdown            Complete 11 seconds ago
dyekgkd0swsualssw4dtvk681    \_ mqtt.3          lcsf/mosquitto3:latest@sha256:beca44e5f916d08730dd19d9d10dd2dcbd3502866f69316806a63bc094a179a9   Docker01            Shutdown            Complete 17 seconds ago`

Comment: Run `journalctl -f -n10` in one terminal and in other terminal try to create the service. You will find the issue in the journalctl terminal. Please report that issue in question

Comment: I couldn't reply the output here, it's too long, then I added it in the question.

Comment: Restart all your nodes and try again

Comment: ```docker service ps --no-trunc {serviceName}``` is a potential way to see the reason for problems as stated in my so thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372848/docker-swarm-how-to-find-out-why-service-cant-start) amongst others.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried it and also restarted the swarm, but still does the same thing.
@herm I added the `docker service ps --no-trunc {serviceName}` output in the question.

Comment: Post your Dockerfile please

Comment: @TarunLalwani Dockerfile posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is your dockerfile. You are running bash command on a swarm service. You need to run a command which doesn't exist

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y mosquitto mosquitto-clients
EXPOSE 80 443 1883 8083 8883
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

This is a infinite tail command, which will make sure your container doesn't exit. Run a command in image that is not looking for user input when deploying to swarm.

Comment: Thanks! Now all the replicas are running! Thanks everyone who helped me.