# Docker Swarm deploy - wait for service/container to be present

Tags: docker, continuous-deployment, docker-swarm

I have a working swarm setup and rolling-updates deployment. As i have to execute some tasks after deployment (like database migrations) i added a "manager" service to the stack. this service is limited to the node-manager - so i always have a way to find it.

To get the current containerID i use this command:
`export MANAGER_ID=$(docker --tls ps --filter label=com.docker.swarm.service.name=projectname-php-manager -q)`

This works ... but not during deploy.

The `stack deploy` exits to soon (befor the container is up) or even befor the manager container gets updated.
I also added a `sleep 10` befor geting the containerID but the results vary.

Is there a way to wait or to know when a specific service is deployed?

The full deploy looks like this (done in a gitlab-ci job - but this is not the root of the problem):

```
deploy:staging:
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://swarm-manager.hostname.tld:2376"
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "/home/gitlab-runner/docker/swarm-manager.hostname.tld"
    VERSION_TAG: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD: "$MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD"
    SECRET_TOKEN: "$SECRET_TOKEN"
  script:
    - docker --tls stack deploy -c docker-compose.prod.yml project-name --with-registry-auth --prune
    - sleep 10
    - export MANAGER_ID=$(docker --tls ps --filter label=com.docker.swarm.service.name=project-name_php-manager -q)
    - docker --tls exec -t $MANAGER_ID bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --allow-no-migration
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://projectname.com
  only: [tags]
  cache: ~
  dependencies:
    - build:app
  tags:
    - deploy
```

Part from docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
php-manager:
    image: dockerhub.mydomain.tld/namespace/projectname/php:${VERSION_TAG}
    environment:
        DATABASE_URL: "mysql://projectname:${MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD}@mysql:3306/projectname?charset=utf8mb4&serverVersion=5.7"
        APP_ENV: prod
        APP_SECRET: "${SECRET_TOKEN}"
        VERSION: "${VERSION_TAG}"
        REDIS_HOST: redis
    networks:
      - default
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Comment: I know that with docker compose you can use "depends_on" to "wait" for a container: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on I am not sure if you can use it when you deploy a stack (and for sure you can not use it when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.)

Comment: You can use depends_on property in docker_compose file which execute the docker images one after other .

Comment: depends_on is not a solution. because for the rolling update I (or the gitlab-ci job) depend on running the current manager container. The other services dont care about it.

i think @herm is on the right track with the polling of the service `.CurrentState` i will give this a try.

Comment: Also 'depends_on' is not supported in stack deploy

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/373) to add this feature to `docker stack deploy`.

Comment: @BMitch yeah, that would solve the whole problem :-) Maybe next year.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Docker stack deploy creates tasks which try to get the system to the state you desire. Sometimes tasks succeed, sometimes they fail and the orchestrator will generate new tasks until the system matches the state described in your yml files.

The bad news: **docker stack deploy does not support blocking until the state you desire is reached.**

Here some how to get the info you want using the docker cli and basic bash tools (which you can surely implement in a similar way in any other language)

In bash you could do `docker service ls --format '{{.ID}} {{.Name}}' | grep ${serviceName}` to get the ServiceId of your service (its the first of the two words returned)

according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_ps/) docker service ps does:

> List the tasks of one or more services

Also it adds some information about the task 'current state' which is the information you care about.

Then you use `docker service ps ${ServiceId} --format '{{.CurrentState}} {{.Image}}' | grep Running.*${newImageName}`

If this command returns something there is a container running with your new image. Hurray :)

I hope this introduces you to all the tools you need. Docker service ps is also helpfull for finding out why a task failed.

FYI: The possible values of task state according to the [Swarm task states documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/swarm-task-states/) are:

> NEW   The task was initialized.
>
> PENDING   Resources for the task were allocated.
>
> ASSIGNED  Docker assigned the task to nodes.
>
> ACCEPTED  The task was accepted by a worker node. If a worker node
>   rejects the task, the state changes to REJECTED.
>
> PREPARING     Docker is preparing the task.
>
> STARTING  Docker is starting the task.
>
> RUNNING   The task is executing.
>
> COMPLETE  The task exited without an error code.
>
> FAILED    The task exited with an error code.
>
> SHUTDOWN  Docker requested the task to shut down.
>
> REJECTED  The worker node rejected the task.
>
> ORPHANED  The node was down for too long.

Comment: Also just because your container is up doesn't mean your application is ready to receive traffic. In order to be sure your application is ready you need a healthcheck that ensures it is ready.