# Docker nginx dev reverse proxy periodically killed

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I use standard nginx config docker container as ingress reverse proxy for applications dev containers.

Additional proxy config looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;  
  server_name app-name.*;
  location / {    
    set $upstream client-wds;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;    
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';    
  }
  location /api {    
    set $upstream server-api;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;    
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
  }
}
```

And periodically containers stops and in logs there just `Killed` line:

[image]

I seems to happend after big GET request.

I wonder what can be a reason of it, is there any advice how to fix it?

Comment: Try to check the logs of docker daemon , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log

Comment: out of memory killer? Should be visible in kernel log.

Comment: I wonder is that "Killed" refers to docker or nginx?