# Location of docker logs in Ubuntu Linux Mint

Tags: docker

I am able to find my application logs using `docker logs --follow containerId`

But which is the physical location of these logs? 
I used this link, But nothing is useful: [Where is the Docker daemon log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log)

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't the docker daemon logs. Those are normally stored in JSON files unless otherwise specified by the driver you select for logging.

They're normally stored in :
`/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log`

But you can verify with 
`docker inspect <container> | grep LogPath`

Comment: Is it possible to configure our own docker log path ?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I would check the documentation with Docker

Answer (score 0):

Docker native command to find log location for any container `docker inspect --format={{.LogPath}} <ContainerName>`

ContainerId can also be used if needed to