# Multiple Teamcity agents with Docker

Tags: docker, teamcity

Ok,
I can somewhat sense my question has nothing to do with Teamcity but rather the subtle issues surrounding docker. I am trying to fire off one Teamcity agent with

```
docker run -it -d -e SERVER_URL="192.168.100.15:8111" \
    --restart always \
    --name="teamcity-agent_1"  \
    --mount src=docker_volumes_1,dst=/var/lib/docker,type=volume \
    --mount src=$(pwd)/config,dst=/etc/docker,type=bind \
    --privileged -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start \
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

Works like a charm. Then I try to fire off a second agent (up to three agents are free). This used to work perfectly fine but has recently stopped...

```
docker run -it -d -e SERVER_URL="192.168.100.15:8111" \
    --restart always \
    --name="teamcity-agent_2"  \
    --mount src=docker_volumes_2,dst=/var/lib/docker,type=volume \
    --mount src=$(pwd)/config,dst=/etc/docker,type=bind \
    --privileged -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start \
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

In this second container docker wouldn't start, e.g. docker images results in

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

service docker start
service docker status
```

Confirm that I have successfully started docker but then going back to docker images and we get the same problem as above. service docker status tells me now that docker is not running!

Comment: does your docker service is running?

Comment: My docker service is running on the host and in the first agent. But not in the 2nd agent. So maybe I can't have multiple agents with that construction?

Comment: all is correct. I checked it

Comment: why not to use `docker-compose` command to start several containers at once?

Comment: check the docker logs for errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing somewhat the same issues, although my errorlog claims:

cgroups: cannot find cgroup mount destination

Comment: For now I am happy with one agent. Haven't tried to fix it for ages