# dockerd: failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy

Tags: docker, sockets, ubuntu, containers, root

I'm running an ubuntu container on windows, and from that I want to run an Nvidia container. To enable GPU support, I have to install the NVIDIA Container Toolkit, but I can do it only on Ubuntu, and therefore I downloaded that container.

I run the Ubuntu container with:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -ti docker
```

Then, I need to follow the guide at this link: https://docs.nvidia.com/ai-enterprise/deployment-guide/dg-docker.html

**Problem**: when I arrive at the step "**Restart the Docker service:**", the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

returns:

```
Running in chroot, ignoring command 'restart'
```

I tried running the container as privileged, and/or setting --pid host, but it doesn't solve it. When typing **dockerd** I get:

```
INFO[2022-06-07T07:53:57.741549000Z] Starting up
failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy
```

The command **sudo /etc/init.d/docker status** gives:

```
* Docker is not running
```

And **sudo /etc/init.d/docker start** only displays **Starting Docker: docker**, but the status remains the same.

When typing the command **sudo systemctl status docker** (boht when I'm as root@ and as an user) I get the message:

```
Running in chroot, ignoring command 'status'
```

The tip that I found (Exit the chroot environment by typing exit or pressing Ctrl+D) doesn't work, I still get that message.

These are the last logs found in var/log/docker.log:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind execute following and copy output in comments:
`sudo journalctl -fu docker.service`

Comment: `No journal files were found.` when exec that command inside the ubuntu container

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log) shows where docker writes it's logs. I want to point this out you may get more information from logs with which you may solve your issue.